# TinyMCE 4 replicate clicking of a toolbar icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have recently migrated from TinyMCE v3 to v4. I have a custom image inserter which was development on v3 and can't get some elements to work on v4.

I'm having issues opening the default image dialog box. In version 3 this was completed using `tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAdvImage');`. I am aware `mceAdvImage` has been removed and have tried using `tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.open('mceImage');`.

Anyone know how to do this? I'm ripping out my hair trying to find a solution.

Comment: Hi - wondering if you ever worked this out - I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue today and found a solution.

My usecase was to open image dialog on double click.

In tinyMCE.init function you need to add this (example):

```
tinyMCE.init({
  ...
  ed.on('DblClick', function(e) {
     if (e.target.nodeName=='IMG') {
       tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceImageDialog');
     }
  });
  ...
});
```

I used a command name 'mceImageDialog' but you can use whatever you want. The key to making this command work is to open image plugin.js and add these lines

**Path:** plugins/image/plugin.js (plugin.min.js):

```
...
editor.addCommand("mceImageDialog", function(ui, val) {
    showDialog();
});
...
```

And thats it. After doubleclick on image element, the image dialog appears. For your solution you need i think only the plugin addCommand and use this command for your purposes.

Hope this helps.